# Javascript function not working when the event is called by element from another function

Tags: javascript

I've downloaded a calendar script, that when the input element is click a calendar will popup.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  $(function() {
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();                
  });   
</script>

<input class='datepicker' />
```

The above code works fine.

But when the element is coming from a javascript...

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function showElement()
{
    $('#mydiv').html("<input class='datepicker' />");

}
</script>

<div id='mydiv'></div>
```

The calendar don't shows up as the input is clicked.
I think there is no error in the downloaded script. I think I need to do something to make this calendar appears even if the element is created by a javascript.
What should I modify? Thanks!

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with creating the element from JavaScript. I think the problem is that you are creating the element _after_  `$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();` has already been called. Maybe you could try calling it again right after creating the input element?

Comment: @JLRishe great. It's works fine now. I now called $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker(); after creating the elemet. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function to:

```
function showElement()
{
    $('#mydiv').html("<input class='datepicker' />");
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();

}
```

Or even better, do the following:

```
function showDatePicker(selector) {
    $(selector).datepicker();
}

function showElement()
{
    $('#mydiv').html("<input class='datepicker' />");
    showDatePicker(".datepicker");
}
```

This way you can show the date picker whenever you want by calling the `showDatePicker()` function for any element that matches the selector you pass as a parameter to the function. Of course in your case you would only want to call it after you have called the `showElement()` function

Comment: Why to do global ".datepicker" match again? It will be enough to match the added element only to call datepicker() on it.

Comment: Good point DrakeES, I just used the jQuery selector that was originally used to be consistent, however you can see in my preferred answer I have provided for using any selector by passing it as a parameter.