# jquery Datepicker error datepicker is not defined

Tags: jquery, datepicker

While using date picker in my code its working when I have not called it inside the function like :

```
 <script src="~/Content/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

            $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
            });
    </script >
```

But when I am calling this inside function :

```
<script src="~/Content/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
        });
    });
</script >
```

its giving me error date picker is not defined. 
Please tell me where I am wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your `bootstrap-datepicker.js` loading? That `~/` looks kind of scary :)

Comment: @VincentOrback its working without function it means path is correct and I have cross check this but no success :(

Comment: Kindly refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121021/javascript-function-not-working-when-the-event-is-called-by-element-from-another

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the src link to a relative link (relative to the html page, that is).

E.g.: if the html page is in Content, the src should be:

```
js/bootstrap-datepicker.js
```